# Which JRE am I using?

Tags: java

There are two varieties of JRE available. [Java VM: IBM vs. Sun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338745/java-vm-ibm-vs-sun).

Is there a way to know which JRE I am using through JavaScript or some Java issued command.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor.url"));
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));

 Sun Microsystems Inc.
 http://java.sun.com/
 1.6.0_11
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: This doesn't distinguish Oracle JRE from OpenJDK - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55002471/476716)

Answer (score 202):

The following command will tell you a lot of information about your `java` version, including the vendor:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```

It works on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: I don't know why people are not voting this one higher since it is the easiest to accomplish in windows and linux. Do you know if it works on Mac?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just tried it on my mac and it doesn't work, good catch

Comment: This command reports Oracle as my Java vendor in my Ubuntu system, despite it being OpenJDK actually.

Comment: @clapas could you please post the version of ubuntu that you are running and the command you used to install java? thanks

Comment: @ErnestoIser Ubuntu 14.04. I installed Java through apt-get.

Answer (score 31):

1. Open up your:

   - command prompt if you're using Windows
   - terminal if you're using mac or Linux
2. Type in:

   ```
   java -version // This will check your JRE version
   javac -version // This will check your Java compiler version if you installed the JDK
   ```
3. Grab a cup of coffee and you're done! You don't need to add the ***.exe*** to the ***java -version*** if everything is installed correctly.

Comment: This just gets version, not JRE vendor

Comment: This does't tell anything about the vendor of your java version, that's the objetive of the question

Answer (score 21):

In Linux:

```
java -version
```

In Windows:

```
java.exe -version
```

If you need more info about the JVM you can call the executable with the parameter `-XshowSettings:properties`. It will show a lot of [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). These properties can also be accessed by means of the static method `System.getProperty(String)` in a Java class. As example this is an excerpt of some of the properties that can be obtained:

```
$ java -XshowSettings:properties -version
[...]
java.specification.version = 1.7
java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version = 1.7.0_95
[...]
```

So if you need to access any of these properties from Java code you can use:

```
System.getProperty("java.specification.version");
System.getProperty("java.vendor");
System.getProperty("java.vendor.url");
System.getProperty("java.version");
```

Take into account that sometimes the *vendor*  is not exposed as clear as *Oracle* or *IBM*. For example,

```
$ java version
"1.6.0_22" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

HotSpot is what Oracle calls their implementation of the JVM. [Check this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) if the vendor does not seem to be shown with `-version`.

Comment: java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: when you see hotspot, it's Sun Java. Sorry, it's Oracle Java now.

Answer (score 4):

Open a command prompt:

```
 Version:  java -version
 Location: where java (in Windows)
           which java (in Unix, Linux, and Mac)
```

To set Java home in Windows:

Right click on *My computer* → *Properties* → *Advanced system settings* → *Environment Variable* → *System Variable* → *New*.
Give the name as JAVA_HOME and the value as (e.g.) c:\programfiles\jdk

Select *Path* and click <kbd>Edit</kbd>, and keep it in the beginning as:
`%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`...remaining settings goes here

[image: JAVA_HOME]

Comment: thx for bringing up the connection between windows environment variables and the used binaries

Comment: Six years after the question was asked and this does absolutely nothing to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

The Java system property `System.getProperty(...)` to consult is `"java.runtime.name"`. This will distinguish between "OpenJDK Runtime Environment" and "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment". They both have the same vendor - "Oracle Corporation".

This property is also included in the output for `java -version`.

Answer (score 1):

**[Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633)** + **Windows 10** + Software that came **bundled with its own JRE copy**:

Do a "Git Bash Here" in the jre/bin folder of the software you installed.

Then use "**./java.exe -version**" *instead* of "**java -version**" to get the
information on the software's copy rather than the copy referenced by your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable.

Get the version of the software installation: **./java.exe -version**

```
JMIM@DESKTOP-JUDCNDL MINGW64 /c/DEV/PROG/EYE_DB/INST/jre/bin
$ ./java.exe -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Get the version in your PATH variable: **java -version**

```
JMIM@DESKTOP-JUDCNDL MINGW64 /c/DEV/PROG/EYE_DB/INST/jre/bin
$ java -version
java version "10" 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)
```

As for **addressing the original question** and getting vendor information:

```
./java.exe -XshowSettings:properties -version ## Software's copy
java       -XshowSettings:properties -version ## Copy in PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

To check actually runned Java version you can use `java.lang.Runtime` API available since Java 10.

```
Runtime.Version version = Runtime.version();
int javaVersion = version.feature();
// returns 17 for Java 17
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are expecting it to know using the Javascript, I believe you want to know the JRE versioned being used in your browser. Hence you can include [Java version tester](http://javatester.org/version.html) applet which can exactly tell you the version of the current browser.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaVersionDisplayApplet extends Applet
{
  private Label m_labVersionVendor;

  public JavaVersionDisplayApplet() // Constructor
  {
    Color colFrameBackground = Color.pink;
    this.setBackground(colFrameBackground);
    m_labVersionVendor = new Label (" Java Version: " +
                                   System.getProperty("java.version") +
                          " from "+System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
    this.add(m_labVersionVendor);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is *"JS"* in this context? *[JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)*? *Java* something? Something else?  (Respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8472187/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "[Edit:](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230693)" [or similar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655)). Thanks in advance.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where my Java applications quit work with no discernible evidence that I could find. It turned out my system started using the 64-bit version rather than the 32-bit version was needed ([Windows Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012)). In Windows, the command:

```
Javaw -version
```

just brought me back to the command prompt without any information. It wasn't until I tried

```
Javaw -Version 2>x.txt
type x.txt
```

that it gave me what was being executed was the 64-bit version. It boiled down to my `PATH` environment variable finding the 64-bit version first.