# How can I tell whether Java is Sun / Oracle / OpenJDK?

Tags: oracle, java, sun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which JRE I am using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472121/which-jre-i-am-using)

I'm trying to figure out whether the Java installation in my HPC environment is running the Sun JVM, or Oracle, or OpenJDK. Since I don't have administrator access and I didn't install Java, is there a quick way I can determine which JVM I have installed?

```
standage@login4:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
standage@login4:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.6.0_03-b05, mixed mode)
standage@login4:~$ uname
Linux
```

Comment: Use the msdos command:
`java -XshowSettings:properties -version`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `java.vendor` property from System.getProperties(), that should give you the info that you're looking for.

On my Mac it's:

```
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
```

Comment: nope, this gives "Sun Microsystems Inc." still. https://gist.github.com/3890869

Comment: the correct answer is java.vm.name  or java.runtime.name.  A one-liner that shows all the system properties helps:  System.getProperties().list(System.out)

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/bin/java vendor 
java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM