# Clicking a Flash button using selenium Webdriver

Tags: flash, selenium, webdriver

I need to automate this widget http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php i'm using selenium Web driver and I have successfully done the AutoIt script for to upload files but for to click the 'Add File ' button on the mentioned url is my problem can anyone please help me on this ..

Thank you

Comment: You can add sikuli script <<http://www.sikuli.org/ >> to your selenium code for handling such flash objects. sikuli simply captures the image and clicks the same image if it is found on the target webpage.

Comment: hi HemChe i have tried the sikuli but im getting this error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\dev10\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplib\VisionProxy.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Comment: check if this link helps !

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro

Comment: hi HemChe thank you for the reply im not able to solve this issue .. now my problem is Sikuli is not Opening for me .. Is there anyother way for flash Automate .

Comment: use Sikuli Web Driver and check if you are still facing the issue.

http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver

Comment: hi HemChe When i have tried that but that also facing that java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: issues but when i tried this https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/BasicUsage its working fine i dont understand how that possible ..

Answer (score 1):

I didnt tried it using webdriver click...but via console i tried to click it on FF, it was working fine for me. You can try this code:

**This is the case when I am supposing that WebDriver click is not working.**

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('uploader_browse').click();");
```