# Fact++ JNI java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: FaCTPlusPlus.initMethodsFieldsIDs()V exception

Tags: owl-api

I wanted to use Fact++ via OWL API. I tried to use libFaCTPlusPlusJNI.so. But it gives me the following exception.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:FaCTPlusPlus.initMethodsFieldsIDs()V
    at FaCTPlusPlus.initMethodsFieldsIDs(Native Method)

```
at FaCTPlusPlus.<clinit>(FaCTPlusPlus.java:30)
at FaCTPlusPlusReasoner.<init>(FaCTPlusPlusReasoner.java:57)
at FactMain.main(FactMain.java:20)
```

Java Result: 1

I am using netbeans for my development.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that FaCT++ native library has not been found. You need to specify the path to the native library with the `-Djava.library.path` argument.
See the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro/6092576#6092576) for more.