# How do you shutdown a ChromeDriver Service?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried for awhile now to try to shutdown the ChromeDriver Service and I can't develop a solution on how to. I am doing a unit test using mocha and chai. The first test passes and the second one fails due to the error.

I tried looking in the selenium-webdrive/chrome.js module and couldn't find a function to close the service. I tried searching for answers but couldn't find anything on the web either. Maybe my approach to creating the chrome driver needs to be reworked. I tried wrapping the creation of the service and the setting of the default service in a if statement using 'selenium-webdriver/chrome.js'.getDefaultService().isRunning() but it fails the first test. I am stumped on this and it is most likely due to lack of knowledge.

This block of called is called during every unit test

```
    var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromePath).build();
    chrome.setDefaultService(service);

    driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
        .build();
```

This is the first unit test which passes without error

```
it('Should pass if the Driver is set to equal the Chrome driver by using chrome', function()
{
        var chromeDriver = Driver( { browserName: 'chrome' } );
        expect(chromeDriver.getCapabilities().browserName).to.equal('Google Chrome');
});
```

This is the second unit test which causes it to fail

```
it('Should pass if the Driver is set to equal the Chrome driver by using google chrome', function()
{
        var chromeDriver = Driver( { browserName: 'google chrome' } );
        expect(chromeDriver.getCapabilities().browserName).to.equal('Google Chrome');
});
```

Error message:

```
Error: The previously configured ChromeDriver service is still running. You must shut it down before you may adjust its configuration.
  at Error (native)
  at Object.setDefaultService (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:346:11)
  at module.exports (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\src\OrasiDriver.js:90:16)
  at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\test\test.js:28:32)
  at callFn (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:315:21)
  at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:308:7)
  at Runner.runTest (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:422:10)
  at C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:533:12
  at next (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:342:14)
  at C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:352:7
  at next (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:284:14)
  at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:320:5)
```

Comment: This post may be able to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320837/release-selenium-chromedriver-exe-from-memory

Comment: I just tried creating a batch file and using require('child_process').exec('cmd /c Kill_ChromeDriver.bat'); in node.js on windows 7.

Comment: Same error message and no new error messages, the batch file is in the same directory as the package.json

Comment: I still need help with this. I have tried various solutions and can't develop a solution that works. I tried running a batch file several times but I can't seem to get it to run the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this command from CMD:

```
taskkill /T /F /IM chromeserver.exe
```

When I use selenium to execute my automation scripts, each time there is a new instance of this driver running (which you can see if you open your task manager).

I use Java for scripting, so what I do is that I add this line for killing any active tasks in the beginning of my test:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /T /F /IM chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: I cant get it to work even with the argument that you provided. I did do some testing and with the setTimeout function I was able to check and make sure the chrome driver is running. I couldn't get exec or spawn to work in any way. I have read the child_processes doc several times.