# What's the docker-compose equivalent of docker run --init?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

According to https://github.com/krallin/tini#using-tini, tini is built into docker, and can be used by passing the `--init` flag to `docker run`.  In my case I'm using docker-compose and don't invoke `docker run` directly.  How can I pass this flag?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are using version 2 of `docker-compose`, the configuration parameter is called `init`.

Example:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  web:
    image: alpine:latest
    init: /usr/libexec/docker-init
```

Please see here for more details: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#init

If you're using docker-compose version 3, apparently this has been removed and [returned in version 3.7](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#init). Please refer to the following ticket: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/3149

Comment: Ah, ok.  It was removed from version 3 but from that ticket it sounds like it is being worked on.  
At the moment, the takeaway is: "While the --init option is not yet supported for services, you can add the tini binary to your images (see the README for tini)."

Comment: As of version 3.7, it's back. Just specify `init: true` for the appropriate service(s). (Requires Docker 18.06)

Comment: Do you know how to set the verbose mode for this service ? is it via a global docker verbose setting i cant seem to be able to find ?

Answer (score 48):

Here is an example from [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#init):

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  web:
    image: alpine:latest
    init: true
```