# Puppeteer: Chromium instances remain active in the background after browser.disconnect

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

**My environment**

- Puppeteer version: 3.1.0
- Platform / OS version: Windows 10
- Node.js version: 12.16.1

**My problem is:**

I have a `for...of` loop to visit 3000+ urls with puppeteer. I use `puppeteer.connect` to `wsEndpoint` so I can reuse one browser instance. I disconnect after each visit and close the tab.

- first 100 urls `page.goto`'s open the urls immediately,
- above 100 `page.goto` uses 2-3 retries per url,
- above 300 `page.goto` uses 5-8 retries per url,
- above 500 I get `TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded` all the time.

I checked the Windows Task Manager and I realized hundreds of Chromium instances running in the background and using 80-90MB of memory each and 1-2% of CPU as well.

**Question**

How can I kill the Chromium instances I've already disconnected with `browser.disconnect` for real?

**Example script**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const urlArray = require('./urls.json') // contains 3000+ urls in an array


async function fn() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
  const browserWSEndpoint = await browser.wsEndpoint()

  for (const url of urlArray) {
    try {
      const browser2 = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint })
      const page = await browser2.newPage()
      await page.goto(url) // in my original code it's also wrapped in a retry function

      // doing cool things with the DOM

      await page.goto('about:blank') // because of you: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1490
      await page.close()
      await browser2.disconnect()
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
  await browser.close()
}
fn()
```

**The error**

The usual puppeteer timeout error.

```
TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
    at C:\[...]\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\LifecycleWatcher.js:100:111
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\[...]\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:94:19)
    at Page.goto (C:\[...]\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:476:53)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\[...]\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:95:27)
    at example (C:\[...]\example.js:13:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  name: 'TimeoutError'
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Finally I was able to achieve the desired result by adding `--single-process` and `--no-zygote` args at launch (+ `--no-sandbox` is required with them).

The number of running Chromium processes aren't growing exponentially anymore, but only two instances remain active: one of them is the usual empty tab in the first position, the second is reused correctly by `puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint })`.

```js
[...]
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--single-process', '--no-zygote', '--no-sandbox']
  })
  const browserWSEndpoint = await browser.wsEndpoint()
[...]
```

- `--single-process`: Runs the renderer and plugins in the same process as the browser [[source]](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#single-process)
- `--no-zygote`: Disables the use of a zygote process for forking child processes. Instead, child processes will be forked and exec'd directly. Note that --no-sandbox should also be used together with this flag because the sandbox needs the zygote to work. [[source]](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#no-zygote)

Comment: Works for me - 1000+ urls and many chromium background processes hanging around. Only needed args:  '--no-zygote', '--no-sandbox'] (in fact --single-process caused an error) and the background processes disappeared.

Comment: Make sure your node does not error out at all. So it actually gets to the browser.close() section. Otherwise it'll never get the chance to close chromium.

Comment: Any idea, on how to scrape capterra review? I have 200+ URLs. On a single URL request, it works fine. But when I start it in a loop, capterra page shows the captcha code. I tried with a timeout, but still, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I run puppeteer inside docker (with docker-compose). Adding `--single-process` and `--no-zygote` did not stop zombie processes being created. What worked for me is adding `init: true` in the `docker-compose.yml` file in the service where puppeteer was run.

```
services:
  web:
    image: alpine:latest
    init: true
```

References

1. https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting#running-puppeteer-in-docker
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64394969/3775598
3. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#init