# How do I Prevent Long Lived Selenium Processes from Generating OOM Errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I prevent containers that use selenium from 'freezing' after getting OOM errors and seeing `Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN)`? What is the root cause and how do I fix it? Further, how can I test the solution locally and how can I implement the solution on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a guide to diagnose and solve OOM issues occurring due to long lived Selenium instances. Specifically, on AWS you will likely get `Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.`  and the dreaded OOM error should your Selenium process run long enough. This guide assumes that you are using Docker and can run your docker file via `docker run <some args if you wish> your_image`.

Diagnosis
Run your app using `docker run ...`. In a separate tab do `docker ps`, find your `Container ID` and do `docker container stats CONTAINER_ID`. The key is to observe the `PIDS` column. Now trigger the selenium process to run, ideally many times (to test this you may want to create a for loop simply to test. You will notice that the PIDs grows without bound. This is because (reference: [Selenium leaves behind running processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518998/selenium-leaves-behind-running-processes)) will leave around zombie processes.

Solution

The solution is to cull the zombie processes. Specifically per [Selenium leaves behind running processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518998/selenium-leaves-behind-running-processes) there is a flag `--init` and this will be the key to the solution. You need to run `docker run --init ...` (note the `--init`). Per https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ "You can use the --init flag to indicate that an init process should be used as the PID 1 in the container. Specifying an init process ensures the usual responsibilities of an init system, such as reaping zombie processes, are performed inside the created container." . To be confident that the solution will work for you, run your image with `docker run --init ...`. Re-trigger the calls to Selenium. This time the PIDS may grow, but not without bound (for me the number of PIDs never passed 200).

Solution - AWS

References are https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-linuxparameters.html and  https://www.ernestchiang.com/en/posts/2021/using-amazon-ecs-exec/
In the 'Task Definition' (search for 'ECS' -> click on `Task Definitions`) select your task definition. Then scroll to the bottom and click on `Configure via JSON`. Next, find `linuxParameters` and, if it is null, replace null with the value:

```
{
"initProcessEnabled": true
}
```

If you already have a JSON value for `linuxParameters` then just add `"initProcessEnabled": true` as a JSON parameter. Next, crate your task definition and deploy!

Solution - Other

I have not used Google Cloud or Microsoft offerings, so I do not know how to add the `--init` flag. If someone with such experience could tell me how to do that, I would be happy to update the guide.