# ChromeDriver.exe process is not closed in Selenium Webdriver (when running via TeamCity)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, teamcity, selenium-chromedriver

I used to run my Selenium tests using Jenkins and all worked good.

Now I changed Jenkins to TeamCity and run my tests **on the same machine** as before but now it's connected to TeamCity.

**The thing is:** when a test stops executing the "chromdriver.exe" process is not closed!

It happens only when I run tests using TeamCity, on my local machine all is good and all is good on the machine I use now but if I use Jenkins.

In order to close chromedriver process I use simple `Dispose();` method.

Here is a screenshot of what is going on after a test ends its executing: http://prntscr.com/c1zlt7

My TeamCity server is installed on Linux and the build agent is on Windows 7, run on System account.

Comment: Will it work for you to kill the process after test run? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21320837/2504101

Comment: Have you tried driver.quit() rather than dispose?

Comment: I tried t use driver.quit() and it didn't help.
I haven't tried to kiss the process with a .bat file. Seems to be too vulnerable solution for me.