# I am trying to kill any chromedriver process

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, selenium-chromedriver

In my scenario if I start Chromedriver.exe I see the process and can find it by name and kill it in my C# application.
But if the chromedriver.exe has an open chrome browser it created, then when I kill the process the chromedriver.exe disappears off of the task manager list but it does not close the chromedriver console window or the chrome browser that the chromedriver opened.

I use this separate exe to close chromedriver if it has been running for an extended period of time usually meaning the website is hung up.

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320837/release-selenium-chromedriver-exe-from-memory/21320949#21320949 ?