# Error display unable to delete the file chromedriver.exe while running a Selenium project in Visual studio

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, visual-studio-2017

I am running a Selenium C# project through Visual studio and suddenly encountered an error

```
Access to the path 'c:\users\documents\visual studio 2017\Project\SeleniumTestProject\SeleniumTestProject\bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe' is denied.
```

I removed the `readonly` attribute for the folder but still get this error. Can anyone please suggest me what could be wrong and solution for the same.

Comment: Something similar sometimes happens to me with FireFox geckodriver.exe.  When I rename the file in Windows Explorer to something else like deleted-geckodriver.exe, I can run my WebDriver tests again.

Answer (score 47):

Just worked when I killed the chrome driver exe from command prompt

- Launch command prompt and enter "taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe"
- Clean your solution

Comment: in my case the chromedriver won't show up in task manager, so this one is effective solution for me

Comment: In our case the `IWebDriver.Dispose()` was implemented correctly, but when the test would crash due to an error, the `Dispose()` was never run so I needed to close it manually from the `Task Manager`.

Answer (score 14):

I solved it by shutting down the ChromeDriver correctly.
I used:
IWebDriver.Dispose() for quitting the ChromeDriver process

In your case, after your test completes, there should be a chromedriver.exe in your Task Manager which does not quit until you manually "End Process" it. However, if you use IWebDriver.Dispose(), it kills the process. And now, since the chromedriver.exe is no longer in use, the "Access denied" problem also goes away.

Hope this solves your problem.
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44126143/1785144

Comment: In our case the `IWebDriver.Dispose()` was implemented correctly, but when the test would crash due to an error, the `Dispose()` was never run so I needed to close it manually from the `Task Manager`.

Answer (score 4):

Deleted the chrome driver exe from command prompt

Launch command prompt and enter "**taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe**" command.
Then rebuild the code again.

Answer (score 2):

'c:\users\documents\visual studio 2017\Project\SeleniumTestProject\SeleniumTestProject\bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe'

First end the process of **chromedriver.exe** from Task Manger, then Delete the **chromedriver.exe** from your project **bin** file and check whether **Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver** package  installed or not, If it's not installed you should install**Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver** package from "NuGet Package Manager"..and rebuild , otherwise rebuild the project directly...

Answer (score 1):

End the `chrome driver process` from task manager.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to remove the `Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver` fixed version that I installed as part of my Nuget package and then cleaned my solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue using visual studio 2017. I'm having to delete the chromdriver process via task manager, clean the solution and then build and start the test. I am also using a driver.Quit() method as my tear down

Answer (score 0):

Hi I ended up downgrading my Chrome version from 58 to 57 whilst using the chromedriver nuget package 2.29 and it seems to be working ok now. haven't workedd out why yet though

Answer (score 0):

Just you can cut chromeDriver.exe from debug folder and paste it to another place, then rebuild the project again

Answer (score 0):

I tried the command `taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe` on the command line and my test ran smoothly. But I needed a way to run this every time before a test run via Visual Studio. So I put it in Project > Properties > Build Events > Pre-build.
When I ran the test, I got an error:

> The command `taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe` exited with code 128.
> The process `chromedriver.exe`not found.

So I used this instead: `taskkill /f /fi "pid gt 0" /im chromedriver.exe`. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

First kill the driver which remain opened in back ground in last failed session run. Kill it by using following command in cmd.

taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe

Now, delete chrome.exe file from bin folder