# Windows, python: how to kill a particular geckodriver.exe instance?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I've python script that launch threads (processes). Each thread launches a class instance with a selenium driver. Driver invokes FF profile to browse the web. After a selenium driver has completed its work I close driver:

```
self.driver.quit()
```

The `geckodriver.exe` turns to still stay in the RAM, consuming memory. See the Task Manager shot:
[image] 
The problem is to remove it from RAM.

Deleting `geckodriver.exe` thru the command `taskkill /F /IM geckodriver.exe` works to kill **all** opened `geckodriver.exe` instances. That is not practical when working multi-threaded or running several script instances.

So, **how to kill a particular geckodriver.exe instance** (and not to stop another opened ones)? Probably we need to do smth. with PID (process ID):

(1) fetch particular `process` ID.

(2) close process in python by PID: `Taskkill /PID 364 /F` where 364 is the pid value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling)

Comment: @DebanjanB, thanks. But the answer there: `taskkill /F /IM geckodriver.exe` works to remove all `geckodriver.exe` instances, killing still needed processes.

Comment: this might also be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320837/release-selenium-chromedriver-exe-from-memory/21320949#21320949)