# Selenium Java: Guarantee chromedriver.exe shutdown when program exits

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, zombie-process

I'm using [`Selenium`](https://www.seleniumhq.org) in Java to automate `Google Chrome`. When my program exits, a `chromedriver.exe` instance is left in memory. I know that I can use `driver.quit()` in e.g. a `finally` block to shut down the current instance. However, if the `Java` application is killed at any time (like during debug sessions), this cleanup is of course never performed.

I'm looking for a solution to make the `chromedriver.exe` a child process of the `Java` process so when the `Java` process exits, the child process also dies automatically. Solutions like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe");` kill all `chromedriver.exe` instances but this may mess up other `Selenium` processes on the system which is not ideal. Also this would not work against forcibly killing the process either.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Selenium Grid" - it has a cleanup cycle of all idle sessions every XXX amount of time (default is 5 minutes) - https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp

This way, your selenium server will take care of calling driver.quit() [which is the preferred way for killing your processes - [release Selenium chromedriver.exe from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320837/release-selenium-chromedriver-exe-from-memory]) even if your Java program is killed.