# How can I close Chrome driver and clear from memory in Selenium C# and SpecFlow using a parallel testing setup?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

Currently when running tests, Chrome driver's stack up and are never fully closed.
Have tried using:

```
driver.Close();
driver.Quit();
driver.Dispose();
```

Relating to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320837/release-selenium-chromedriver-exe-from-memory)

But the Chrome drivers still seem to exist after tests have run / finished.

After scenario hook:

```
        [AfterScenario]
public void AfterScenario()
{
    var driver = _objectContainer.Resolve<IWebDriver>();
    driver?.Quit();
    driver?.Dispose();
}
```

After feature hook:

```
    [AfterFeature]
public static void AfterFeature(FeatureContext featureContext)
{
    var driverService = featureContext.Get<ChromeDriverService>();
    driverService.Dispose();
}
```

Running 4 tests in parallel currently so want to avoid closing all browsers by accident.

Have confirmed the **`AfterScenario`** is being called when a scenario finishes but they still seem to be lurking and slowing down my machine locally when they stack up. As mentioned I have tried `driver.Close()` but this hasn't helped.

- Chromeversion: 85.0.4183.8700
- Specflow - 3.0.225
- Selenium webdriver - 3.141

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a ChromeDriverService available, kill the process explicitly in your `[AfterScenario]` hook:

```
[AfterScenario]
public void AfterScenario()
{
    // Add a FeatureContext parameter to the class constructor if need be
    var driverService = featureContext.Get<ChromeDriverService>();
    var driver = _objectContainer.Resolve<IWebDriver>();

    try
    {
        if (driverService.ProcessId != default)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Attempting to kill web driver service process #" + driverService.ProcessId);

            var process = Process.GetByProcessId(driverService.ProcessId);

            process.Kill();
            Trace.WriteLine("   > Done killing process #" + driverService.ProcessId);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Exception thrown when killing web driver service: " + ex);
    }

    try
    {
        driverService.Dispose();
        Trace.WriteLine("Web driver service disposed of.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Exception thrown when disposing of web driver service: " + ex);
    }

    driver?.Close();
    driver?.Quit();
    driver?.Dispose();
}
```

Since Chrome 85, I've noticed that these ChromeDriver.exe processes are not cleaning up as easily as they were before. You would think the `Dispose()` method would kill the process, but lately I've had to add some extra strength cleanup and error handling.