# How to close chrome manually and do .quit() automatically

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

My script is in python with selenium is to login automatically on some site and after(i use chrome like any browser), I want when I finish to use chrome (when I close it), automatically close the chromedriver.exe else the chromedriver.exe is all time running.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a duplicate [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320837/release-selenium-chromedriver-exe-from-memory).
Try following the up-voted answer.

Another thing, this looks [like a problem](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6317) others are facing so follow the answers there