# Does Selenium quit() affect other instances?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know this is a trivial question but no description of the close and quit function answered my question. I want to run 2 python scripts in parallel and close them properly by calling the quit() function. What I don´t understand is: Does quit() close the instance of the second script too ?

Is this a XY Problem? Maybe since this question came up when i noticed that calling close() leaves me with a lot of used ram and dead webdriver/chrome processes. So to put it in other words: how do I exit selenium in a clean way?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320837/release-selenium-chromedriver-exe-from-memory), maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21320949/) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely clear that `quit()` method applied on particular `driver` object will close that particular `driver` session only.
This can not have any influence on any other `driver` objects / sessions if you have such anywhere in you system / memory / anywhere in the universe.
Normally we use `close()` method only if we want to close some open browser **tab** and probably to continue working on the same `driver` object / session. In case you want to close the entire session `quit()` method should be used.