# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, lpsolve

I am new to lp solve.
I am trying to run the following code and getting the following error:

```
    package package1;

/**
 * Created by ANJANEY on 6/13/2014.
 */

import lpsolve.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Create a problem with 4 variables and 0 constraints
            LpSolve solver = LpSolve.makeLp(0, 4);

            // add constraints
            solver.strAddConstraint("3 2 2 1", LpSolve.LE, 4);
            solver.strAddConstraint("0 4 3 1", LpSolve.GE, 3);

            // set objective function
            solver.strSetObjFn("2 3 -2 3");

            // solve the problem
            solver.solve();

            // print solution
            System.out.println("Value of objective function: " + solver.getObjective());
            double[] var = solver.getPtrVariables();
            for (int i = 0; i < var.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Value of var[" + i + "] = " + var[i]);
            }

            // delete the problem and free memory
            solver.deleteLp();
        }
        catch (LpSolveException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:E:\HIVEMINDS\ThirdProject\lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win64\lpsolve55j.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
at lpsolve.LpSolve.<clinit>(LpSolve.java:275)
at package1.Demo.main(Demo.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you load correct libraries in other classes with System.loadlibrary?

If yes, I think quick solution can be putting all libraries in a folder that exists in os's PATH (for instance system32, windows) This has worked for me everytime if there is no any other issue