# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no indri_jni in java.library.path

Tags: java

I am working on lemur tool and i am running with some problem.

when i execute the code , java complains

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no indri_jni in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at lemurproject.indri.indriJNI.<clinit>(indriJNI.java:109)
at lemurproject.indri.IndexEnvironment.<init>(IndexEnvironment.java:39)
at indritest.main(indritest.java:9)
```

this is My code

```
    import lemurproject.indri.*;
public class indritest
{
    public static void main ( String[] args ) 
    {
        try {

            String [] stopwords = {"a", "an", "the", "of"};
            IndexEnvironment env = new IndexEnvironment();
            env.setStoreDocs(true);
            env.setStopwords(stopwords);
            env.create("aaa"); 
            env.addFile("trekfile.txt", "booomer.txt");
            env.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using
jdk 1.8.0_11 x64bit ,
windows 7 ultimate x64bit ,
indri5.7 x64bit ,
eclipse juno x64bit.

.....................................................................................................................................................................
EDIT:-

I worked with the solution given by **RALF WAGNER** now my console is showing this Bug.
after printed the System.getProperty("java.library.path") in my console i am getting this output. indri_jni.dll is already present in system32 folder.

My code.

```
 import lemurproject.indri.*;
public class indritest
{
    public static void main ( String[] args ) 
    {
        try {
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
            //System.loadLibrary("indri_jni");
            String [] stopwords = {"a", "an", "the", "of"};
            IndexEnvironment env = new IndexEnvironment();
            env.setStoreDocs(true);
            env.setStopwords(stopwords);
            env.create("aaa"); 
            env.addFile("trekfile.txt", "booomer.txt");
            env.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My console outout.

```
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files\Indri\Indri 5.7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Indri\Indri 5.7\bin\indri_jni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1929)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1847)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at lemurproject.indri.indriJNI.<clinit>(indriJNI.java:109)
    at lemurproject.indri.IndexEnvironment.<init>(IndexEnvironment.java:39)
    at indritest.main(indritest.java:10)
```

Comment: java -Djava.library.path= "<path_of_your_application>" –jar <ApplicationJAR.jar>

This might help.

Comment: Run Dependency Walker on `indri_jni.dll` and see what DLLs it requires that you don't have.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200

Comment: Thanks frnds , I got my bug cleared with the help of dependency walker ... Thnk u LUKE WOODWARD and RALF WANGER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the Java classes from the project you're using a native library i.e. a library that is not written in Java.
You need to add the native library to your class path and may need to load the library before using any classes like `IndexEnvironment` by calling

```
System.loadLibrary("<NAME OF THE LIBRARY>");
```

From the stack trace I'd guess that the library is called "indri_jni", so I think on Windows you should add "indri_jni.dll" to your Windows path. This usually includes the working directory of the application so you may have to put the library there or add the directory where the library is found to your path environment variable.

Comment: (1) Putting the native library on the classpath does **not** help.  On Windows, the native library must be on the `PATH`.  Print out `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` to see if you've got the path set up correctly. (2) There's no need to load the library yourself - as you can see from the stacktrace the `IndexEnvironment` class is loading the library itself via the `indriJNI` class.

Comment: Luke: (1) You're right, I've changed the description.

Comment: Luke: (2) Right again, it's not actually necessary. But I'd prefer the code to fail early and have the dependency clearly in the code.