# What's the search sequence for the java project to find dlls?

Tags: java, eclipse, dll

I have a java project which will use native library, like some dlls. However, there are many dlls with the same name in my computer. I want to make my new built java project to use a specific dll. Where should I put this dll that will make it be called?

I think there must have a config option for this java project but I don't know what it is. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix an UnsatisfiedLinkError (Can't find dependent libraries) in a JNI project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java, we always use **System.loadLibrary("MyDll");** to load native DLL. However, if your system has multi same dlls, you can use System.load(fullPath + "MyDll.dll") to indicate which one you want to use.