# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, c#, environment-variables, sikuli

I am trying to use SikuliIntegrator in a C# Winforms project on my Windows 64 bit laptop and it won't run because:
`Additional information: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplib\VisionProxy.dll: Can't find dependent libraries`

I've looked online as much as possible for the last 2 hours and I have added these variables to the System Environment Variables:

- SIKULI_HOME = C:\SikuliX
- JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
- PATH= %Path%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SIKULI_HOME%\libs;

Still won't work. What am i missing???

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sikuli , but have you tried the NuGet install ?

Comment: Actually I did :) I installed it from the NuGet Manager but that's where it started going wrong so I downloaded and installed the IDE for Sikuli to be able to create an Environement Variable

Comment: Do you habve the VisionProxy DLL in your project with the attribute to Copy Always ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix an UnsatisfiedLinkError (Can't find dependent libraries) in a JNI project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro). Java does not use `JAVA_HOME` or `CLASSPATH` on Windows to locate libraries on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was using Java 7 and that is not supported so I did the following:

Installation Steps:

1. Download and install Sikuli using the self-extracting installer:
   Sikuli-X-1.0rc3 (r905)-win32.exe. After installation is completed, a
   folder named Sikuli X should be created on your system.
2. Do not start using Sikuli X now because it has some bugs.
3. Download the following zip file: Sikuli X r930. This contains
   important bug fixes Open the downloaded zip file and locate the
   folder called SIKULI-IDE. Copy the content in SIKULI-IDE to Sikuli X. The purpose of this step is to replace the files associated with r905 (the buggy
   version) by the files associated with r930 that has the most recent
   bug fixes.