# How to solve "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries" without System32?

Tags: java, c++, windows, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm working on a Java project on Eclipse, which uses C++ OpenCV libraries via JNI. Some image processing algorithms are implemented with OpenCV on the native side, and I wish to use them from java using JNI.

I have built a C++ DLL project to link to Java, which resulted in a `MyLibrary.dll` file. I compiled OpenCV with GCC 6.3 compiler and I compiled the C++ code with the same GCC 6.3 compiler on Eclipse CDT (along with MinGW Linker). I also checked if there are any dependency issues using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). I had no errors thus far.

Afterwards, I tried to load the library from Java code as follows:
`System.loadLibrary("MyLibrary")`

I have set the path with `-Djava.library.path=path\to\MyLibrary`, and and made sure that JVM knows the address of the native libraries. I also added the required OpenCV libraries next to `MyLibrary.dll`.

However I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: MyLibrary.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
...
```

Then the problem goes away, when I move the dependent OpenCV libraries into the `System32` folder.

My question is; how can I solve this issue **without moving** the required DLL files into the `System32` folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix an UnsatisfiedLinkError (Can't find dependent libraries) in a JNI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best practice for this issue is to load dependent libraries by yourself with calling the library load method:

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv_1");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_2");
...
```

After you load dependent libararies now you can safely load your own dll file with the same way:

```
System.loadLibrary("MyFile");
```

This should resolve the `can't file dependent libraries` error.

Another workaround (no the best practice) is to copy dependent dll files (in your case opencv dlls) to System32 folder.

Why this is happening?

I think, when you set `java.library.path` argument, you are responsible to load dependent libraries of the library, not the OS itself. I'm not sure to be honest.

As mentioned in the [How to fix an UnsatisfiedLinkError (Can't find dependent libraries) in a JNI project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092576/1537318)
,  you can check your path by adding `-XshowSettings:properties -version` argument to the virtual machine.

Comment: @isacikgoz It seems obvious now, but when the error message kept saying: "Can't find dependent libraries" I didn't know that there really were other libraries that would need to be loaded.  I used a DLL dependency walker to find the dependent libraries and loaded them as you suggest and now it works!  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For ones who are hitting the complain: `Can't find dependent libraries` and visiting this post for a solution:

this complain means that the dll which failed to load is depending on some other dlls. By using a depedency walker: http://www.dependencywalker.com/,   we can tell what dlls are required. By loading them ( `System.loadLibrary("dependedDll");` ) before the failed loading dll, we can solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this after coming across this bug report:

https://www.mail-archive.com/openjfx-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg22016.html

"As previously mentioned, the above exception is not thrown on machines where the Visual C++ 2019 redistributable is installed."

I downloaded the MS Visual C++ redistributable for 2015-2019 and installed it on two different computers with diff combinations of offAdoptJDK, jre_8u_202, and jre_8u_265, and this resolved my issue.

I downloaded the redistributable from the link below:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

For Windows 10, I installed "x64: vc_redist.x64.exe" above to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add because I experience this also. I use **[dependency walker](https://dependencywalker.com)** and found that I needed to load `opencv_world455.dll` first before loading my dll.