# java/jni: Can't find dependent libraries in windows

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

**I get this error message**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\flex\test\lib\native\mylib.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

`mylib.dll` is a `JNI Wrapper` which uses other `C-Libraries`.

When I open `mylib.dll` with `Dependency Walker` it shows that all dependent libraries are available!

Is there a way to check which library is not found within `java`?

I compiled the `3rd party` libraries with Visual Studio and `mylib` with `mingw32`. ***could that be a problem?***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries" without System32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536366/how-to-solve-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-wi)

Answer (score 0):

you are using windows then you need to put `dll` into current working directory. or you can also use `java.library.path` system property.