# Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, youtube-api, java-native-interface

I executed youtube watch me android application project. I just add some classes in my project and build with ndk. I got the error like

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.ephronsystem.mobilizerapp.Ffmpeg.encodeVideoFrame(byte[]) (tried Java_com_ephronsystem_mobilizerapp_Ffmpeg_encodeVideoFrame and Java_com_ephronsystem_mobilizerapp_Ffmpeg_encodeVideoFrame___3B).

My code:

```
package com.ephronsystem.mobilizerapp;

public class Ffmpeg {

     static {
        System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
    }

    public static native boolean init(int width, int height, int audio_sample_rate, String rtmpUrl);

    public static native void shutdown();

    // Returns the size of the encoded frame.
    public static native int encodeVideoFrame(byte[] yuv_image);

    public static native int encodeAudioFrame(short[] audio_data, int length);
}
```

This is ffmpeg-jni.c

```
 #include <android/log.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavutil/opt.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_ephronsystem_mobilizerapp_Ffmpeg_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                                 jint width, jint height,
                                                                 jint audio_sample_rate,
                                                                 jstring rtmp_url);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_ephronsystem_mobilizerapp_Ffmpeg_shutdown(JNIEnv *env,
jobject thiz
);
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_ephronsystem_mobilizerapp_Ffmpeg_encodeVideoFrame(JNIEnv
*env,
jobject thiz,
        jbyteArray
yuv_image);
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_ephronsystem_mobilizerapp_Ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                             jobject thiz,
                                                                             jshortArray audio_data,
                                                                             jint length);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ffmpeg-jni", __VA_ARGS__)
#define URL_WRONLY 2
        static AVFormatContext *fmt_context;
        static AVStream *video_stream;
        static AVStream *audio_stream;

        static int pts
= 0;
static int last_audio_pts = 0;

// Buffers for UV format conversion
static unsigned char *u_buf;
static unsigned char *v_buf;

static int enable_audio = 1;
static int64_t audio_samples_written = 0;
static int audio_sample_rate = 0;

// Stupid buffer for audio samples. Not even a proper ring buffer
#define AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE 16384  // 2x what we get from Java
static short audio_buf[AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE];
static int audio_buf_size = 0;

void AudioBuffer_Push(const short *audio, int num_samples) {
    if (audio_buf_size >= AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE - num_samples) {
        LOGI("AUDIO BUFFER OVERFLOW: %i + %i > %i", audio_buf_size, num_samples,
             AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_samples; i++) {
        audio_buf[audio_buf_size++] = audio[i];
    }
}

int AudioBuffer_Size() { return audio_buf_size; }

short *AudioBuffer_Get() { return audio_buf; }

void AudioBuffer_Pop(int num_samples) {
    if (num_samples > audio_buf_size) {
        LOGI("Audio buffer Pop WTF: %i vs %i", num_samples, audio_buf_size);
        return;
    }
    memmove(audio_buf, audio_buf + num_samples, num_samples * sizeof(short));
    audio_buf_size -= num_samples;
}

void AudioBuffer_Clear() {
    memset(audio_buf, 0, sizeof(audio_buf));
    audio_buf_size = 0;
}

static void log_callback(void *ptr, int level, const char *fmt, va_list vl) {
    char x[2048];
    vsnprintf(x, 2048, fmt, vl);
    LOGI(x);
}

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_ephronsystem_mobilizerapp_Ffmpeg_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                                 jint width, jint height,
                                                                 jint audio_sample_rate_param,
                                                                 jstring rtmp_url) {
    avcodec_register_all();
    av_register_all();
    av_log_set_callback(log_callback);

    fmt_context = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("flv", NULL, NULL);
    if (ofmt) {
        LOGI("av_guess_format returned %s", ofmt->long_name);
    } else {
        LOGI("av_guess_format fail");
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    fmt_context->oformat = ofmt;
    LOGI("creating video stream");
    video_stream = av_new_stream(fmt_context, 0);

    if (enable_audio) {
        LOGI("creating audio stream");
        audio_stream = av_new_stream(fmt_context, 1);
    }

    // Open Video Codec.
    // ======================
    AVCodec *video_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!video_codec) {
        LOGI("Did not find the video codec");
        return JNI_FALSE;  // leak!
    } else {
        LOGI("Video codec found!");
    }
    AVCodecContext *video_codec_ctx = video_stream->codec;
    video_codec_ctx->codec_id = video_codec->id;
    video_codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    video_codec_ctx->level = 31;

    video_codec_ctx->width = width;
    video_codec_ctx->height = height;
    video_codec_ctx->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    video_codec_ctx->rc_max_rate = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->rc_buffer_size = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->gop_size = 12;
    video_codec_ctx->max_b_frames = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->slices = 8;
    video_codec_ctx->b_frame_strategy = 1;
    video_codec_ctx->coder_type = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->me_cmp = 1;
    video_codec_ctx->me_range = 16;
    video_codec_ctx->qmin = 10;
    video_codec_ctx->qmax = 51;
    video_codec_ctx->keyint_min = 25;
    video_codec_ctx->refs = 3;
    video_codec_ctx->trellis = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->scenechange_threshold = 40;
    video_codec_ctx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_LOOP_FILTER;
    video_codec_ctx->me_method = ME_HEX;
    video_codec_ctx->me_subpel_quality = 6;
    video_codec_ctx->i_quant_factor = 0.71;
    video_codec_ctx->qcompress = 0.6;
    video_codec_ctx->max_qdiff = 4;
    video_codec_ctx->time_base.den = 10;
    video_codec_ctx->time_base.num = 1;
    video_codec_ctx->bit_rate = 3200 * 1000;
    video_codec_ctx->bit_rate_tolerance = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->flags2 |= 0x00000100;

    fmt_context->bit_rate = 4000 * 1000;

    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx, "partitions", "i8x8,i4x4,p8x8,b8x8", 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "direct-pred", 1, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "rc-lookahead", 0, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "fast-pskip", 1, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "mixed-refs", 1, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "8x8dct", 0, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "weightb", 0, 0);

    if (fmt_context->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        video_codec_ctx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    LOGI("Opening video codec");
    AVDictionary *vopts = NULL;
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "profile", "main", 0);
    //av_dict_set(&vopts, "vprofile", "main", 0);
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "rc-lookahead", 0, 0);
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "tune", "film", 0);
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "tune", "film", 0);
    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "tune", "film", 0);
    int open_res = avcodec_open2(video_codec_ctx, video_codec, &vopts);
    if (open_res < 0) {
        LOGI("Error opening video codec: %i", open_res);
        return JNI_FALSE;   // leak!
    }

    // Open Audio Codec.
    // ======================

    if (enable_audio) {
        AudioBuffer_Clear();
        audio_sample_rate = audio_sample_rate_param;
        AVCodec *audio_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
        if (!audio_codec) {
            LOGI("Did not find the audio codec");
            return JNI_FALSE;  // leak!
        } else {
            LOGI("Audio codec found!");
        }
        AVCodecContext *audio_codec_ctx = audio_stream->codec;
        audio_codec_ctx->codec_id = audio_codec->id;
        audio_codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO;
        audio_codec_ctx->bit_rate = 128000;
        audio_codec_ctx->bit_rate_tolerance = 16000;
        audio_codec_ctx->channels = 1;
        audio_codec_ctx->profile = FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW;
        audio_codec_ctx->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT;
        audio_codec_ctx->sample_rate = 44100;

        LOGI("Opening audio codec");
        AVDictionary *opts = NULL;
        av_dict_set(&opts, "strict", "experimental", 0);
        open_res = avcodec_open2(audio_codec_ctx, audio_codec, &opts);
        LOGI("audio frame size: %i", audio_codec_ctx->frame_size);

        if (open_res < 0) {
            LOGI("Error opening audio codec: %i", open_res);
            return JNI_FALSE;   // leak!
        }
    }

    const jbyte *url = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, rtmp_url, NULL);

    // Point to an output file
    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (avio_open(&fmt_context->pb, url, URL_WRONLY) < 0) {
            LOGI("ERROR: Could not open file %s", url);
            return JNI_FALSE;  // leak!
        }
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, rtmp_url, url);

    LOGI("Writing output header.");
    // Write file header
    if (avformat_write_header(fmt_context, NULL) != 0) {
        LOGI("ERROR: av_write_header failed");
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    pts = 0;
    last_audio_pts = 0;
    audio_samples_written = 0;

    // Initialize buffers for UV format conversion
    int frame_size = video_codec_ctx->width * video_codec_ctx->height;
    u_buf = (unsigned char *) av_malloc(frame_size / 4);
    v_buf = (unsigned char *) av_malloc(frame_size / 4);

    LOGI("ffmpeg encoding init done");
    return JNI_TRUE;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_ephronsystem_mobilizerapp_Ffmpeg_shutdown(JNIEnv
*env,
jobject thiz
) {
av_write_trailer(fmt_context);
avio_close(fmt_context
->pb);
avcodec_close(video_stream
->codec);
if (enable_audio) {
avcodec_close(audio_stream
->codec);
}
av_free(fmt_context);
av_free(u_buf);
av_free(v_buf);

fmt_context = NULL;
u_buf = NULL;
v_buf = NULL;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_ephronsystem_mobilizerapp_Ffmpeg_encodeVideoFrame(JNIEnv
*env,
jobject thiz,
        jbyteArray
yuv_image) {
int yuv_length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, yuv_image);
unsigned char *yuv_data = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, yuv_image, 0);

AVCodecContext *video_codec_ctx = video_stream->codec;
//LOGI("Yuv size: %i w: %i h: %i", yuv_length, video_codec_ctx->width, video_codec_ctx->height);

int frame_size = video_codec_ctx->width * video_codec_ctx->height;

const unsigned char *uv = yuv_data + frame_size;

// Convert YUV from NV12 to I420. Y channel is the same so we don't touch it,
// we just have to deinterleave UV.
for (
int i = 0;
i < frame_size / 4; i++) {
v_buf[i] = uv[i * 2];
u_buf[i] = uv[i * 2 + 1];
}

AVFrame source;
memset(&source, 0, sizeof(AVFrame));
source.data[0] =
yuv_data;
source.data[1] =
u_buf;
source.data[2] =
v_buf;
source.linesize[0] = video_codec_ctx->
width;
source.linesize[1] = video_codec_ctx->width / 2;
source.linesize[2] = video_codec_ctx->width / 2;

// only for bitrate regulation. irrelevant for sync.
source.
pts = pts;
pts++;

int out_length = frame_size + (frame_size / 2);
unsigned char *out = (unsigned char *) av_malloc(out_length);
int compressed_length = avcodec_encode_video(video_codec_ctx, out, out_length, &source);

(*env)->
ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, yuv_image, yuv_data,
0);

// Write to file too
if (compressed_length > 0) {
AVPacket pkt;
av_init_packet(&pkt);
pkt.
pts = last_audio_pts;
if (video_codec_ctx->coded_frame && video_codec_ctx->coded_frame->key_frame) {
pkt.flags |= 0x0001;
}
pkt.
stream_index = video_stream->index;
pkt.
data = out;
pkt.
size = compressed_length;
if (
av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_context,
&pkt) != 0) {
LOGI("Error writing video frame");
}
} else {
LOGI("??? compressed_length <= 0");
}

last_audio_pts++;

av_free(out);
return
compressed_length;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_ephronsystem_mobilizerapp_Ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame(JNIEnv
*env,
jobject thiz,
        jshortArray
audio_data,
jint length
) {
if (!enable_audio) {
return 0;
}

short *audio = (*env)->GetShortArrayElements(env, audio_data, 0);
//LOGI("java audio buffer size: %i", length);

AVCodecContext *audio_codec_ctx = audio_stream->codec;

unsigned char *out = av_malloc(128000);

AudioBuffer_Push(audio, length
);

int total_compressed = 0;
while (

AudioBuffer_Size()

>= audio_codec_ctx->frame_size) {
AVPacket pkt;
av_init_packet(&pkt);

int compressed_length = avcodec_encode_audio(audio_codec_ctx, out, 128000,
                                             AudioBuffer_Get());

total_compressed +=
compressed_length;
audio_samples_written += audio_codec_ctx->
frame_size;

int new_pts = (audio_samples_written * 1000) / audio_sample_rate;
if (compressed_length > 0) {
pkt.
size = compressed_length;
pkt.
pts = new_pts;
last_audio_pts = new_pts;
//LOGI("audio_samples_written: %i  comp_length: %i   pts: %i", (int)audio_samples_written, (int)compressed_length, (int)new_pts);
pkt.flags |= 0x0001;
pkt.
stream_index = audio_stream->index;
pkt.
data = out;
if (
av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_context,
&pkt) != 0) {
LOGI("Error writing audio frame");
}
}
AudioBuffer_Pop(audio_codec_ctx
->frame_size);
}

(*env)->
ReleaseShortArrayElements(env, audio_data, audio,
0);

av_free(out);
return
total_compressed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error generally occurs when your native library can't be found by JVM during execution. Your native code must be compiled into .so file and make it available for JVM during run time.

You may find more details on java.library.path and linking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro)

Comment: What is meant by linkage error?. I have no ndk path in my project. how to set the ndk path in android studio

Comment: @MuthukumarSubramaniam @upendra if i copy `.so` file to `jniLibs` directly, will it work or we need `ndk` to be present ?

Answer (score 0):

in all of this methods, as a second parameter you take `jobject thizz` - that means you try to implement non-static method that will get reference to `jobject` that this method is running against.

Try changing those to `jclass clazz` to mark them as you would like to implement those as static methods

Comment: Again the same error is occured during runtime.In compile time the methods are displayed in red color