# Unsatisfied link error inside intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using JNI (Java-Native-Interface) to acess some code that was written in c++. Everything works fine when I run the code from the command line but when I add the code to my Intellij project (class, header-file and dll) it gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\egdb_example\end.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

My Java Code looks like this :

```
public class EndGame {

    public static native void openDataBase(int maxPieces, int buffer);

    public static native void test();

    public static native int lookUp(int condition, int BP, int WP, int K, int color);

    public static native void close();

    static {

        System.load("C:\\Users\\Robin\\Desktop\\egdb_example\\end.dll");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Kleiner Test");
        openDataBase(8, 2000);
        int value = lookUp(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        close();
    }

}
```

I checked whether the path is actually correct running this piece of code

```
File test = new File("C:\\Users\\Robin\\Desktop\\egdb_example");

        for (File file : test.listFiles()){
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }
```

which produces the outcome:

```
.git
.gitattributes
.gitignore
egdb.h
egdb.lib
egdb64.dll
egdb64.lib
egdb_example.cpp
egdb_example.vcxproj
egdb_example.vcxproj.filters
end.dll
EndGame.class
EndGame.h
EndGame.java
jni.h
jni_md.h
main.cpp
Readme.pdf
robin.cpp
robin.exe
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: are you sure that the path is correct?

Comment: @YCF_L : double checked that now. See my edit

Comment: did u read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro ?

Comment: Check the [dependencies of your DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency). Make sure they are also in `java.library.path` or in `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here to see how to setup IntelliJ and CLion to debug code.

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-D002/

If you don't use CLion, simply skip that part and take a look solely at IntelliJ configuration.