# Affectiva SDK not working in Samsung S8+

Tags: android, affdex-sdk

The Error which i am getting is

```
09-21 04:23:01.793 22764-23207/com.***.**** E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FrameDetectorThread
                                                                Process: com.***.****, PID: 22764
                                                                java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.****.****-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.***.****-2/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.***.****-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libaffdexface_jni.so"
```

This code actually runs fine in all devices with 'armeabi-v7a'.

I think Affectiva is not providing 'libaffdexface_jni.so' file for 'arm64-v8a'.

please, tell me where to get it or is there anything i can do to make it work in 'arm64-v8a'(Samsung S8).

Thank You

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro

Comment: Hey @Pavan, Apologies for the delayed reply. I am sure by now you might have figured out that the Affectiva SDK for Android only supports the armeabi-v7a architecture. I am curious to know if you had a fix for making it working on arm64-v8a?