# Error launching my app

Tags: android, android-activity

Please i am trying to run my android app from my phone but it keeps bringing Session app failed.

Here is what i have in my logcat

```
$ adb push C:\Users\oracle\AndroidStudioProjects\Oracle\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.oracle.oracle
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.oracle.oracle"
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:64)
    at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:354)
    at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:488)
    at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:96)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:187)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
```

this is my manifest file . I have Mainactivity as my Launcher,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.oracle.oracle">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DrawerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drawer"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also, my instant run is unchecked. yet i am getting same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck enable ADB integration options

**Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB integration -> uncheck.**

You can check it LATER if you need to debug your project after successful installation on device

This is working on android studio 2.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are having this problem using JNI libs.

Try to set the classpath properly.

Here is something related this already Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro) out.

Here is JNI [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) for more info.