# JNI use .hpp library inside C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, cygwin

I am trying to use JNI with C++. I'm able to create a Hello-World JNI project following [this](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) tutorial.

But, I want to use [JSON for modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) inside my C++ function. This library contains only a `json.hpp` file that I include inside my project.
Everything compile well, I got my `hello.dll` file but when I run my Java application, I got this error :

```
$ java HelloJNI java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Levio-CIL\Desktop\TEST\hello.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at HelloJNI.<clinit>(HelloJNI.java:3) Exception in thread "main"
```

I did some tests, and it seems that the .dll can't find the function inside `json.hpp`. When I remove this function, everything works well. The C++ program can also run successfully as a standalone.

**HelloJNI.java:**

```
public class HelloJNI {
   static {
      System.loadLibrary("hello"); 
   }

   private native void sayHello();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new HelloJNI().sayHello();  // invoke the native method
   }
}
```

**HelloJNI.cpp:**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "HelloJNI.h"
#include "json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::json;

// Implementation of native method sayHello() of HelloJNI class
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {

    json specific_data = json::parse("{\"id\": \"aa\",\"value\": 1,\"type\": \"water\"}"); //THE PROBLEMATIC LINE
    printf("Hello world");
    return;
}
```

**Additional Information :**

I'm Using Windows 10 with cygwin64.

I compile my c++ file with this command :

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.cpp json.hpp
```

Every file is inside the same directory.

**EDIT :**
I included missing library provided by Dependency Walker but still got the same error. (And Yes, I run with the .dll inside my workdir)

Comment: Is the json.hpp a pure include file (which contains only declarations), or does it also contain the implementations of all the class methods?

Comment: @RannLifshitz It's a single include file located here https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix an UnsatisfiedLinkError (Can't find dependent libraries) in a JNI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro)

Comment: I also read this post before posting but no, it's not a duplicate. I have only one DLL, it's not a problem to link it, my problem is to use a .hpp file inside this .dll.

Comment: @Gazouu No, you don't have just one DLL.  You have one DLL that you compiled, *and that DLL is also dependent on other DLL(s)*.  You need to identify those DLL(s) and make sure your JVM can find them, per the other question.

Comment: Then perhaps the issue is to close the json.hpp in a .dll of it's own, then link it to your own generated .dll, while keeping the json.dll in a recognizable path for the JVM to find during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove hpp from your command,

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.cpp
```

If the error persists, check the DLL dependencies using the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com).

Comment: I tried with and without the .hpp and still same problem

Comment: And what do you see in dependency walker?

Comment: Some errors like : "Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2)." But I also get these errors when I open the working hello.dll

Comment: Ok, I may need "LIBGCC_S_SEH-1.DLL" and "LIBSTDC++-6.DLL"

Comment: Cool! This makes sense, because the empty JNI function, that you get when you temove the json call, does not need these libraries.

Comment: Hum, I still have the same error with both DLL (I run "java -Djava.library.path=. HelloJNI")

Comment: Did you copy the missing libraries to your working directory? This may not be enough, because they have more dependencies of their own.