# Futronic sdk ftscanapi library not found in file path

Tags: java, netbeans, fingerprint

trying to load library in file path for finger printing using futronic sdk. On opening it gives error of library not foundi nfile path.

Have used cmd command to set to library path but it does not work.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ftrJavaScanAPI in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at com.Futronic.ScanApiHelper.Scanner.<clinit>(Scanner.java:91)
at com.Futronic.ScanApiEx.MainForm.<init>(MainForm.java:38)
at com.Futronic.ScanApiEx.MainForm$11.run(MainForm.java:503)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: win 7 64 bit operating system , are you recommanding that it will work on 32 bit operating system.

Comment: Your path should contain the directory where ftrjavascanapi.dll is located. There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro) on how to do that. I do *not* use windows, but I guess you may test by putting ftrjavascanapi.dll in c:\windows\system32\.

Comment: well i had to explicitly copy ftrscanapi.dll provided inside sdk to win/system32 from here it was working.