# Exported a project and getting this error

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
        at renderEngine.DisplayManager.createDisplay(DisplayManager.java:23)
        at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:45)
```

this is the error that i get saying that there is no lwjgl how could i fix this
I got this error after I exported the project since when i had it in the jde it worked just fine

```
java -jar Ecosistembio.jar -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Eco\lib
```

This is the command i have tried using thought its to no result

Answer (score -1):

Your path no have the necessary dependency(artifact) for the **Ecosistembio.jar**.

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092576/10354937

Comment: so for me to make it work i need to add another variable to the computer to tell it where to search for?

Comment: UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native, is one of the frustrating error you will get if your application is using native libraries e.g..DLL in Windows or .SO.  check https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/javalangunsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in.html