# Struts2 and PI4J

Tags: java, struts2, pi4j

I tryied to use a Struts2 web framework with PI4J to change relays status on Rapsberry 3B+ device on Tomcat 9 web container.

My Action class.

```
    package com.action;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
    import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
    import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
    import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
    import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
    import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;


    public class RelayAction extends ActionSupport  {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RelayAction.class);

        // create gpio controller
       final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();


        // provision gpio pin as an output pin and turn on
       final GpioPinDigitalOutput output = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_23, "My Output", PinState.HIGH);

       public String on() {

            logger.error("Start execute : ");


            output.setState(PinState.HIGH); // or ... output.high();


            return SUCCESS;
        }

        public String off() {

            logger.error("Start execute : ");


           output.setState(PinState.LOW); // or ... output.high();


            return SUCCESS;
        }

    }
```

My JSP

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <title>Pokaż temperaturę</title>
    <style>
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) {
        html {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust : none;
            text-size-adjust         : none;
        }
        /* adapt the rest of the mobile interface here */
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Przekaznik</h2>
        <s:form action="relayAction" method="post">



        <s:submit value="ON" align="center" method="on" />
        <s:submit value="OFF" align="center" method="off"/>
        </s:form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

When execute I get error type
Exception report

message Filter execution threw an exception

```
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.wiringPiSetup()I
    com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.wiringPiSetup(Native Method)
    com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiGpioProvider.<init>(RaspiGpioProvider.java:69)
    com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiGpioProvider.<init>(RaspiGpioProvider.java:51)
    com.pi4j.platform.Platform.getGpioProvider(Platform.java:125)
    com.pi4j.platform.Platform.getGpioProvider(Platform.java:118)
    com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getDefaultProvider(GpioFactory.java:109)
    com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.<init>(GpioControllerImpl.java:53)
    com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getInstance(GpioFactory.java:91)
    com.action.RelayAction.<init>(RelayAction.java:21)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:131)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:162)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:121)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:293)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:393)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:534)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

Aditionally I created Java swing application with code and I can change a status of replays with buttons in application.Output when run on Windows.

```
cze 11, 2020 9:19:28 PM com.pi4j.util.NativeLibraryLoader load
SEVERE: Unable to load [libpi4j.so] using path: [/lib/raspberrypi/dynamic/libpi4j.so]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The path has to be absolute, but found: \lib\raspberrypi\dynamic\libpi4j.so
    at com.pi4j.util.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromClasspath(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
    at com.pi4j.util.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:105)
    at com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.<clinit>(Gpio.java:189)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiGpioProvider.<init>(RaspiGpioProvider.java:69)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiGpioProvider.<init>(RaspiGpioProvider.java:51)
    at com.pi4j.platform.Platform.getGpioProvider(Platform.java:125)
    at com.pi4j.platform.Platform.getGpioProvider(Platform.java:118)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getDefaultProvider(GpioFactory.java:109)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.<init>(GpioControllerImpl.java:53)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getInstance(GpioFactory.java:91)
    at main.Main$2.actionPerformed(Main.java:62)
```

Have sombebody use Struts2 with PI4J to change a relays status?

UPDATE: 
I found this in logs

[2020-06-11 19:08:54] [info] Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/Relay.war]
[2020-06-11 19:09:14] [info] At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were sc$
[2020-06-11 19:09:15] [info] Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/Relay.war] has finished in [21,194] ms
[2020-06-11 19:09:24] [info] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[2020-06-11 19:09:24] [info] WARNING: Illegal reflective access by ognl.OgnlRuntime (file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/Relay/WEB-INF/lib/ognl-3.0.6.jar) to method java.uti$
[2020-06-11 19:09:24] [info] WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of ognl.OgnlRuntime
[2020-06-11 19:09:24] [info] WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[2020-06-11 19:09:24] [info] WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2020-06-11 19:09:28] [info] wiringPiSetup: Unable to open /dev/mem or /dev/gpiomem: Brak dostępu.
[2020-06-11 19:09:28] [info]   Aborting your program because if it can not access the GPIO
[2020-06-11 19:09:28] [info]   hardware then it most certianly won't work
[2020-06-11 19:09:28] [info]   Try running with sudo?

Most important is 
**Unable to open /dev/mem or /dev/gpiomem: No access. Let me check it abd back to you.**

UPDATE: 
It starst to work by adding user tomcat8 to gpio group

sudo adduser tomcat8 gpio

Thanks for all viewers of my post!

Please let me know. 
Sławek,

Comment: Missing some native libraries can be fixed with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6092200/573032) question.