# would a "bad" library cause java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm modifying a program but it throws the ULE even though the native path contains the requested libraries.  I verified by printing them out.  If the libraries were somehow "bad", would that cause this exception?  I.e. if they can't be read, then they're not found.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro) help?

Comment: It could definitely cause that exception. Are you sure the library works?

Comment: I'm sure it works on an Intel cpu running Ubuntu 16.04.  I'm now trying on an AMD with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Konrad - I rebuilt the libraries and they're found now.  So, incompatible libraries will cause the ULE.